# Lost /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: raspbian-buster, source.list

Very new to raspberry pi and I am interested in using opencpn to build a autopilot for a boat.  While attempting to download opencpn (trying to follow directions and not succeeding). I have lost my `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I was told to add this PPA to the end and I think I deleted some important lines in the process

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/opencpn/opencpn/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

Now it reads not found after entering the source list code

So my question is do I need a new 1. raspbian or just a 2.new source list how would I accomplish the second

Comment: See https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository . Obviously, you need to replace `wheezy` with whatever Raspbian flavor you actually have.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what OS you are using, but the sources for Raspbian Buster should be something like:-

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

Restoring it should be OK.

NOTE 1 I NEVER use `sudo nano` - you should use `sudoedit` which edits a temporary file.

NOTE 2 `raspbian.raspberrypi.org` is slow and unreliable. I replace with a local mirror; in my case `deb http://raspbian.melbourneitmirror.net/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi` although you could select a local mirror from https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors/

NOTE 3 I rarely edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but add additional repositories to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` I have `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list` among others.

NOTE 4 I don't know who suggested using a Ubuntu build; it may or may not work; it is safer to build from source.

Comment: Sorry yes buster.  Working backward Ubuntu is in the instructions from opencpn.org.  I will read up on 2&3 more to understand those differences.  For point #1 sudo edit is used so that....?  I’m not editing/ corrupting the source?  Lastly while I’m in source.list It did have the above code but I deleted that line to enter what I thought was in the directions and now it comes up blank

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to say - just restore the contents of the file as listed above. The other comments are just recommendations for good practice.